# Sum information with date restriction

Tags: python, pandas, filter, group-by

I just want to sum by ID and a given value the total depending of a range of dates

I tried this:

```
days=(360)
import datetime 
import pandas as pd
group = None
df=pd.read_excel(r'C:\Users\xxxx\Desktop\xxxxx.xlsx')
for i in days:
        D = ((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=i)))
        B = D <= df['DATE']
        group = df.groupby('ID')['VALUE'].filter(lambda x: B ).sum()
```

df:

```
DATE       ID  VALUE
2019-01-01 1    10
2019-02-01 2    15
2019-03-01 1    12
```

But there is an error

```
TypeError: the filter must return a boolean result
```

Even with the type of B is bool

The result that I need is:

```
    ID Value
     1  22
     2  15
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you need filtering by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) before `groupby`:

```
 group = df[B].groupby('ID')['VALUE'].sum()
```

Or:

```
 D = ((datetime.datetime.now()-datetime.timedelta(days=i)))
 B = df.loc[D <= df['DATE'], 'VALUE']
 group = B.groupby(df['ID']).sum()
```